# Azure Web App Backup Failed website + database size exceeds limit but database not configured for backup

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App configured for Backups.  Both automated and manually initiated Backups fail with the log message "The website + database size exceeds the 10 GB limit for backups. Your content size is 10.9 GB..."

The web app files total about 800 KB.  The database it uses is over 10 GB.  However, the Backups overview in the portal shows "Databases: Not configured".  The Configure Backup Settings shows Database Settings, "No Database Backups Active".

Why is my backup failing with the log message about website + database size too large when the backup does not appear to be configured to backup the database?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I'm an engineer Microsoft who works on this feature. If you provide the name of your web app, I can look into this issue. If you don't want to share that information publicly, you can follow the steps here: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly

Comment: related web app is MyDummyWebApp

Comment: Can you provide a small additional hint about the name of the web app that is having issues? Since you have multiple apps, I will need a little more information.

Comment: Per the link you gave me, "Create a new dummy site in the same App Service Plan".  MyDummyWebApp is in an App Service Plan with only two apps, MyDummyWebApp and the one of concern.  It contains the word 'Fleet'.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the web app is configured with a backup schedule that has a database setting. I'd suggest going to the portal and changing some part of the schedule (for example, the backup frequency) to try to "refresh" it. Please take note of the time when you do this, because if there are still problems, knowing the time will help me diagnose the issue.

Comment: Apparently I spoke too soon.  Changing then saving the settings, then click backup gives the message 'Backup created successfully' and shows it as Created in the list of backups.  Going back later / Refresh shows it failed for the same reason as before.  I cannot get it to succeed and actually create a backup in the selected storage.